# I want to use job1 workspace in job2(cd to job1 workspace using jenkins pipeline) But i am getting error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use job1 workspace in job2(cd to job1 workspace using jenkins pipeline) But i am getting below error.

Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 5: unexpected char: '\' @ line 5, column 14.

```
   bat cd E:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Job1

            ^
```

1 error

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:350)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:139)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:234)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:168)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:320)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Finished: FAILURE
Page generated: Au

I tried below pipeline to cd but no luck. It is failing to change directory

stage "build"

```
bat e:

bat cd E:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Job1

bat "\"${tool 'MSBuils'}\" project1\project1.sln /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:LastUsedBuildConfiguration=Release /p:LastUsedPlatform=AnyCPU /p:ExcludeApp_Data=False /p:publishUrl=C:\Published\ /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True"
```

Please provide a solution to use the jenkins workspace of job1 in job2

Edit:

I have seen option to copyartifact (plugin). But i don't want to copy those ( as the folder structure will disturb)i just want to Cd to job1 workspace and run my MSbuild command

Comment: I have seen option to copyartifact. But i don't want to copy those ( as the folder structure will disturb)i just want to Cd to job1 workspace and run my MSbuild command

Comment: try `bat 'cd "E:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Job1"'`,